# Scrapy Request somehow cuts the URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

i like to spider a url that looks like this:
https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p1_popular_desc

Because the End is dynamic, i create the list of urls in parse and then make a request loop.

The Problem is, that he cuts the url after appid=730 - so each url looks the same. If i switch to dont_filter=true, i see he loops again and again over page1. I dont get the Problem :(

the "x" in the code will get dynamic later (thats the start_url is needed for), think that has nothing to do with the issue.

Seems he always crawls from the referer url, not the one i gave him. the url may **not** end by 730.

#### The Debug message:

```
...

2019-03-28 23:44:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730> (referer: None)

2019-03-28 23:44:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) **<GET https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p7_popular_desc> (referer: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730)**

...

2019-03-28 23:44:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730>
{'item_count': u'7,899',
 'item_name': u'Prisma Case',
 'item_price': u'$2.79 USD',
 'item_subtext': u'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive'}
2019-03-28 23:44:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: **Scraped from <200 https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730>**
{'item_count': u'192,519',
 'item_name': u'Danger Zone Case',
 'item_price': u'$0.30 USD',
 'item_subtext': u'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive'}
```

---

```
allowed_domains = ['steamcommunity.com/market']
start_urls = ['https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730']

def parse(self, response):
    x = 15 
    steam_xpath = [u'//steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p'+str(i)+'_popular_desc' for i in range(1, x)]
    for link in steam_xpath:
        yield Request(response.urljoin(link), self.parse_steam, dont_filter=True)

def parse_steam(self, response):
    xitem_name = response.xpath('//span[@class="market_listing_item_name"]/text()').extract()
    xitem_price = response.xpath('//span[@class="normal_price"]/text()').extract()
    xitem_subtext = response.xpath('//span[@class="market_listing_game_name"]/text()').extract()
    xitem_count = response.xpath('//span[@class="market_listing_num_listings_qty"]/text()').extract()
    for item in zip(xitem_name, xitem_price, xitem_subtext, xitem_count):
        new_item = SteammarketItem()
        new_item['item_name'] = item[0]
        new_item['item_price'] = item[1]
        new_item['item_subtext'] = item[2]
        new_item['item_count'] = item[3]
        yield new_item
```

expected: 150 results, 10 by each url in the loop.

actual: 15 results, but each 10 times - all from the first url.

Answer (score 0):

The URL on the address bar appears as you say, but if you inspect the requests on the Network tab of your browser developer tool you will see the request that returns new items is this:

> https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&appid=730

This Json contains the page HTML on the field `results_html`, you can create a selector with this value if you want to get the data using xpath.

```
import json

def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    sel = scrapy.Selector(text=data['results_html'])
    # then use sel
    value = sel.xpath('//value').get()
```

Reading the response of this URL you can also notice there is a `tip` saying it is also possible to add a parameter `&norender=1` to the URL and don't work with HTML at all. So it is up to you to choose what you are most comfortable with.

Lots of sites do this so you have to keep an eye on the requests and don't always trust what appears on the the address bar. I advise you to never even trust what appear on the "inspector" and always check the source code (right click > See page source code).